# My custom system app doesn't toggle FlightMode as it should

Tags: android, service

My girlfriend has a problem with her Samsung Galaxy S with Cyanogenmod 10.2. Every time she restarts her phone, the APN list is empty and she can't add new (which means she can't use mobile internet nor send/receive MMS). To temporarily fix it until next reboot, she needs to turn airplane mode on, wait few seconds, and then turn airplane mode off again.

To ease things up, I've written a simple application which is supposed to do it instead of her. But it doesn't work - I see in logs that the app was started, but it doesn't toggle Airplane mode.

Permissions should be set correctly, I even installed the app into /system/app to make Android think it's a system app. The permissions are displayed correctly when I look at the application in Applications list.

Here's my code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cz.berzeger.autoflightmode"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <service android:name=".AutoFlightModeService" android:label="AutoFlightMode Service" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".ServiceReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="ServiceReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

ServiceReceiver.java

```
package cz.berzeger.autoflightmode;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, AutoFlightModeService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

AutoFlightModeService.java:

```
package cz.berzeger.autoflightmode;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;


public class AutoFlightModeService extends Service {  


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Turn AirPlane mode on
        Settings.Global.putString(getContentResolver(), "airplane_mode_on", "1");


        // All services run in one thread. We need to explicitly create a new thread,
        // if we want to implement non-blocking wait.
        new Thread( new Runnable() {
            public void run()  {
                try  { Thread.sleep( 5000 ); }
                catch (InterruptedException ie)  {}
                // After 5 seconds, turn Airplane mode off
                Settings.Global.putString(getContentResolver(), "airplane_mode_on", "0");
            }
        }).start();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, a little change - it looks like it doesn't run after boot. One time it did then it stopped doing it. In logs, I only see "Installed" log, but not my Log.d() message I have added. The one time it did work, I saw the message.

Comment: accessing the airplane_mode is not possible starting from android 4.2

Comment: It is possible for system apps - which mine is.

Answer (score 1):

```
adb shell ls system/

addon.d

app

bin

blobs

build.prop

etc

extras

fonts

framework

lib

lost+found

media

***priv-app***

recovery-from-boot.p

tts

usr

vendor

xbin
```

The app needs to be installed in priv-app to take the system permissions.

Comment: I don't see such a folder in my /system/ folder even with "Show hidden files" turned on. :( I'm using ES File Explorer.

Comment: That folder only exists in KitKat, I believe Cyanogenmod 10.2 is only JellyBean 4.3.